# Having trouble with java loops

Tags: java, loops

I am doing a project for school where i need to make a game about guessing the number from the computer. The problem I have is that my code won't print out the sentence "Het is fout" Which means that they are wrong. It also wont print the sentence that they tried to many times even tho it stops when they are over the limit. My teacher won't help me so I am desperate for some help. This is the code I wrote:

```
    while(leesinvoer() != toeval)
    {
        aantalkeer = aantalkeer + 1;
        if(leesinvoer() == toeval)
        {               
            System.out.println("Het is goed het goede nummer was:"+ toeval);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Het is fout");
        }
        if(aantalkeer > pogingen)
        {
            System.out.println("U heeft te vaak beprobeerd");
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(toevalsgetalmaken(grens));
}

public static int toevalsgetalmaken(int grens)
{
    Random toeval = new Random();
    int toevalsgetal = toeval.nextInt(grens);
    return toevalsgetal;
}
public static int leesinvoer()
{
    String tekst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Doe een gok","GOKJE",3);
    int getal = Integer.parseInt(tekst);
    return getal;
}
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Your code isn't complete enough to run, and it's hard to follow (for me, as an English speaker), because it's in Dutch (I'm guessing!). Please can you help me out, and add some more code, so it's a [mcve]?

Comment: Whel I am really inexperienced with Java so this is the code I got. You got the language right btw. The code needs to run in the program EditPlus so it doesnt need to go online. Also I got the basic stuff for the int above the code I shared. A quick translaten is that leesinvoer is the popup that comes and asks for your input. Toevalsgetalmaken also toeval is the method to make a random number. Aantalkeer is the counter for the amount of times you guessed. My code System.out.println wont print the lines for the counter and for every time I guess wrong

Comment: while(leesinvoer() != toeval) is opposite to this if(leesinvoer() == toeval) then System.out.println("Het is goed het goede nummer was:"+ toeval); won't print forever its a dead code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invoke `leesinvoer()` once for each time you check it in your `if()` statement.

But your code is invoking `leesinvoer()` twice in each loop: once from `while` statement, and once from the `if` statement.

So, instead of `while(leesinvoer() != toeval)` do `while(true)`, but better yet, (since this should give you a compiler warning saying "condition is always true",) do `for(;;)` which essentially loops forever.

Then, after each `System.out()` statement, (which essentially signifies a decision, which should end the loop,) do `break;` to exit the loop.

Goedenavond! C-:=

Comment: Dude you litterly saved my whole year/education with this simpel answer. I owe you my whole future. Thank you so much

Comment: LOL!   Glad to be of help!  C-:=

Comment: Guess who's back. I hope you can help me 1 more time. I need to add the function of giving tips. I want it to say whether your input is higher or lower than the random number. But when i do it with adding another if statement like if(leesinvoer() < toeval) { System.out.println("Higher"); I get "het is fout" the one time and "Higher" the other time. Also by adding a new if in stead of "Het is fout" i get the problem of dubbel what i got earlier. Could you help me out 1 last time?

Comment: Invoke `leesinvoer()` just ***once*** per iteration of your loop, and store the result in a variable.  Like this: `int invoer = leesinvoer();` Then, work with that variable.  If this does not help, then please post another question.  It may be answered by someone else.  If it gets complicated, post an [mcve].